# Can't install Bumblebee on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, 13.10

I have a newly installed Ubuntu 13.10, and I have followed instructions from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee. 
The first two steps are:

1. (not needed for 13.10 Saucy and newer) `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable`
2. Enable the Universe and Multiverse repositories (for bumblebee and nvidia packages respectively).

   These two steps are OK.
   But the third step is:
3. `sudo apt-get update`

   After invoke this command, here is the result:

   ```
   W: can not dowload http://ppa.launchpad.net/bumblebee/stable/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
   E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
   ```

   Also, the forth step is:
4. `sudo apt-get install bumblebee virtualgl linux-headers-generic`

There is no virtualgl on Ubuntu 13.10.

I think there is no Bumblebee package for Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy.

Answer (score 6):

bumblebee is in ubuntu 13.10's official repository so you can easily install it.

`sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia`(if it's nvidia)